# What is the best tool to convert WSDL to objective c client stub?

Tags: iphone

Can anyone suggest me on which is best tool to convert a WSDL to objective c client stub for iPhone? I am aware of WSDL2OBJC and SUDC tool. Which is a best tool and gives memory leak free client stubs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WSDL2OBJC and have been extremely happy with it. I'm not aware of SUDC and nor can I find anything about it, do you have a link?

Comment: Hi Roger, Please use the following link " http://sudzc.com/ " to know about sudzc. I am sorry i miss spelled the toll name, actual tool name is SUDZC. Please check and suggest me which is best.